# OpenSSL BIGNUM — is there a bitwise & function?

Tags: c, openssl, bit-manipulation, bignum

I am using the BIGNUM library from OpenSSL and I need to do a calculation in an if statement as follows:

```
if (expo & 1)
```

I know for bit shifting there are functions. Is there a function corresponding to this kind of operation (where `expo` is a `BIGNUM*`)? If not, is there a way to carry this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

```
bool BN_is_bit_set( const BIGNUM *a, int n );
```

... it behaves exactly like the bitwise operator `AND`. For example, to see if the right-most bit is on I would call the function as follows:

```
bool is_set = BN_is_bit_set( ptr_my_bignum, 0x1 );
```

... notice my mask is `0x1` (which implies `1` in binary). More information on the BIGNUM library can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bn_mask_bits).

Comment: Are the bits numbered from 0 or 1?